# Rails 2.3.5 connecting to Sql Server 2005

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sql-server-2005, activerecord

I've got an application running on Rails 2.3.5, on a Linux box, and I need to connect to Sql Server 2005 for one of my models.

I've been reading up on this, and it's getting frustrating, can't find a solution that works thus far. I've done this before using JRuby and JDBC, but I can't use Java in this scenario.

Any pointers to a failsafe method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 3 days of research, this route seems to work: http://www.metaskills.net/2009/9/5/the-ultimate-os-x-snow-leopard-stack-for-rails-development-x86_64-macports-ruby-1-8-1-9-sql-server-more